# Magento 2.0.2 Backend cms pages and blocks disappeared

Tags: magento2

After deleting a store my cms and static block pages have become unviewable under admin. Instead I'm left with the error below. I tried to reindex and delete any cache files I could find even though I'm sure this is a db problem. Just not sure how to approach it, any help would be appreciated.

> Notice: Undefined index: store_id in
>   /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Store.php
>   on line 82

Comment: Looks like a bug. Can you create issue on github?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3317

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a table that match *cms_pages* and *stores* (`cms_page_store`), to find any relation error you can make a Left Join to determine if some page isn't assigned to any store:

```
SELECT cp.page_id, cp.identifier, cps.store_id FROM cms_page AS cp
LEFT JOIN cms_page_store as cps on cps.page_id = cp.page_id
```

If you see some page without store like here:

[image]

Just add a new record to `cms_page_store` for that/those page/s. with value = 0 (admin)

Comment: Thank you. I had to add values to cms_page_store and cms_block_store as they were both null. Any idea what caused this?

Comment: Yes, the store deletion, seems to be a problem for magento (since V1) the store deletion collateral tasks, when you remove a store, store-specific tables as catalog_flat_{store_id} and catalogsearch_fultext_scope{store_id} still existing in the database. I think that is basically a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the answer from @MauroNigrele :
If your problem is with a block instead of a page, run this query:

```
SELECT cp.block_id, cp.identifier, cps.store_id FROM cms_block AS cp LEFT JOIN cms_block_store as cps on cps.block_id = cp.block_id;
```

If you notice that the block with **block_id** = 3 has NULL for **store_id**, your insert query should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO cms_block_store (block_id, store_id) VALUES (3,0);
```

This should fix any errors caused by this.